# why Json encode return error after new xampp installed php?

Tags: php, json

I have `json` encode method, I use this to built an api to return `json` data. It's work perfectly, but after I install `Xampp` new version again this will display an error:

> Note - This works perfectly on my previous xampp, this error came
> after i installed new xampp

```php
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

           $myObj[$a]->id   = $row["district_code"];
           $myObj[$a]->name = $row["district_name"];
           $myObj[$a]->type = 'District';

           $a++;

     }

    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
    echo $myJSON;
}
?>
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "id" on null

Comment: Xampp probably upgraded your PHP version. You should probably check what you're installing instead of just randomly downloading all upgrades.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `$myObj` first, for example with `$myObj = new stdClass();`, before assigning properties to it.

Comment: `$myObj = new stdClass();` doesn't work with array like this `$myObj[$a]->type = 'District';`